# Why I cannot use boost correctly with CMake?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, clion

I will try to explain in detail the difficulties I encountered.

Recently I want to use boost libraries in Ubuntu Mint 18 x64. So I download the newest version of it which is 1.62.0. Sha256sum is fine. Then I started compiled it with "./bootstrap.sh" and "./b2". Finally copied then to "/usr/local" with "sudo ./b2 install". So far so good.

I am using Clion right now, so new job is to add libraries in Cmakelist.txt. Code below is what I have added.

```
set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.62.0)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(BoostTest main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

First thing I want to explain is that I know it is not good to set up a specific location in CMake, but without it Cmake cannot find it. So I just do that. And, at this moment, CMake did not post any error info.  Here is my hello_world demo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/testable_mutex.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I just include a .hpp for test, nothing else. When I attemped to run it. I got these.

```
-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vita-nove/ClionProjects/BoostTest/cmake-build-debug
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable BoostTest
CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'BoostTest' failed
make[3]: *** [BoostTest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BoostTest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'BoostTest' failed
make: *** [BoostTest] Error 2
```

Wired thing is that I do find some .hpp file in External Libraries. They are all located in /include/boost. In /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include/boost everything shows up as I expect.

Sorry for my bad English. After spending nearly whole day searching and testing I cannot solve it. I don't know what dependencies I have missed or something else. Anyway, Thank you for reading this, hope someone will help.

Comment: You may turn `BOOST_ROOT` into a user-configurable path by writing `set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local" CACHE PATH "Boost installation prefix")`, so that your hard-coded value will become just a default, not an enforced one.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Thank you for comment. Tried, but still the same. I did not use "-prefix" arguement while building, maybe that is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell cmake that you need the thread library

```
set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.62.0 COMPONENTS thread system) # <-- here
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(BoostTest main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I already tried this, but saddly I got some error info. CMake Warning at /home/vita-nove/Applications/clion-2016.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/vita-nove/Applications/clion-2016.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /home/vita-nove/Applications/clion-2016.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)

Comment: Sorry for the bad format. So I just thinking about is there something wrong happened while I compiling and moving it lead to the missing dependencies. I did not use any parameter.

Comment: so have you compiled and installed the boost libraries into /usr/local ?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure about that. They are located in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include to be exact. Do I have to add some info into PATH or somewhere else? Really confused.

Comment: what I would do is remove the BOOST_ROOT line and on the command line add this: `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local <src_dir>`

Comment: also, did you make the correct version of boost? do you have another version lying around somewhere that's being found first?

Comment: have a look in the CMakeCache.txt file and see what's been found